# What is called the diffraction phase in an interferometer?

Tags: optics, atomic-physics, diffraction, interferometry

I'm reading articles about atom interferometers using Bragg diffraction to split the atom beam. It says the beam splitter causes an unwanted phase shift between transmitted and reflected waves? So what exactly is that?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide references to these articles?